# Google and Yahoo Signon for Phonegap Stockmarket application

Tags: android, cordova, mobile-application, yahoo-finance, google-finance

Can any one suggest me an example to implement Google login and yahoo login for my android application developing using PhoneGap, I want to import google and yahoo finance portfolios in to my application.

Comment: FYI - Google Finance API going down on October 20, 2012 [source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/google-finance-apis/q-DbjbzQDGQ/5s8m4hra5S8J)

Answer (score 0):

Find more about google api's here :

https://developers.google.com/accounts/

Find more about yahoo api's here :

http://developer.yahoo.com/auth/